# NavBar Button Clicks (need 2 clicks rather than 1 click)

Tags: buttons

For some reason the NavBar buttons on my website require 2 mouse clicks to activate the button (one click then a 2nd click before the page the button is coded for will load)...rather than the normal 1 click most NavBar buttons use.

Is there a WordPress setting that I can use to adjust this so the Navbar buttons activate with 1-click?

Thanks

Comment: No, there is not a WordPress setting. However, there could possibly be a Theme or Plugin setting. Could you share what Plugin or Theme you are using that is providing the NavBar you are having issues with?

Comment: Sounds like an overlay z-index bug or so, I would monitor where the first focus is coming from OR where the current focus is when you click. Just a guess in the dark - please provide more info like Nathan Powell already wrote.

Comment: Thanks guys for the replies.  I should have mentioned that it's a custom theme.  Basically what happens is...if you hover over the NavBar button with your mouse...then click once...nothing happens.  Then if you click a 2nd time on the same Navbar button...then the page linked to the button loads.  All the buttons on the NavBar do this.  Thanks